# alternative definition of the spatial norm on tensor products

Tags: normed-spaces, tensor-products, c-star-algebras, estimation

In lecture, for $C^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$, the minimal tensor norm on the *-algebraic tensor product $A\odot B$ was defined as follows: 
$$\|\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\otimes b_i\|_{\min}=\sup\{\|\pi_A\otimes \pi_B)(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\otimes b_i)\|: \pi_a:A\to B(H_1),\pi_B:B\to B(H_2)\;\ast-\text{representations}\}.$$

Since all non degenerate $*$-representations $\pi :A\to B(H)$ can be decomposed in a direct sum of cyclic $*$-representations, I want to prove that 
$\sup\{\|\pi_A\otimes \pi_B)(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\otimes b_i)\|: \pi_a,\pi_B\;\ast-\text{representations}\}=\sup\{\|\eta_A\otimes \eta_B)(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\otimes b_i)\|: (\eta_A,v_{\eta_A}), \;(\eta_B,v_{\eta_B})\;\;\text{cyclic *-representations}\}$ without using the fact that $\|\enspace \|_{min}$ is the smallest tensor norm.

The estimation $\sup\{\|\pi_A\otimes \pi_B)(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\otimes b_i)\|: \pi_a,\pi_B\;\ast-\text{representations}\}\ge\sup\{\|\eta_A\otimes \eta_B)(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\otimes b_i)\|: (\eta_A,v_{\eta_A}), \;(\eta_B,v_{\eta_B})\;\;\text{cyclic *-representations}\}$ is clear, but I don't know how to prove the other estimation $\le$. I can decompose all the *-representations $\pi_a,\pi_B$ into cyclic representations, but nevertheless then it's not clear for me why $\sup\{\|\pi_A\otimes \pi_B)(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\otimes b_i)\|: \pi_a,\pi_B\;\ast-\text{representations}\}\le\sup\{\|\eta_A\otimes \eta_B)(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\otimes b_i)\|: (\eta_A,v_{\eta_A}), \;(\eta_B,v_{\eta_B})\;\;\text{cyclic *-representations}\}$ should be true. How to prove this?

Comment: With your argument you get that sup$\{||(\pi_A \otimes \pi_B)(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\otimes b_i)|| : \pi_A,\pi_B $*-representations$\}=sup\{||\pi(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\otimes b_i)|| : \pi:A\odot B\to B(H)$ is a cyclic representation$\}$. However, if the restrictions are cyclic, then so is the representation, but the converse is not necessarily true. I mean, there exist cyclic representations with non-cyclic restriction (I think...), so I also don't know how to get an equality in your question. There are places where they define the minimal norm like that?

Comment: thanks for your comment. Indeed, the equality in your comment is correct. Unfortunately, I haven't find this definition with cyclic representations in the literature yet, the equality in my question is used in a proof which we had in lecture (I will ask the professor when worse comes to worse). The equality iny my question should be true since the spatial norm can be defined in this way: $\|\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\otimes b_i\|_{\min}=\sup\{\|\pi_A\otimes \pi_B)(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\otimes b_i)\|: \pi_a,\pi_B\;\ast-\text{representations}\}$...

Comment: .. but also in this way: $\|x\|_{\min}=\|\pi_A\otimes \pi_B)(x)\|$ where $\pi:A\to B(H_1)$ and $\pi:B\to B(H_2)$ are faithful *-representations. But I can't use this fact since it's not allowed to use the minimality-argument at this point .

Comment: OK, I see now that the notations $\pi_A, \pi_B$ confused me... I thought you mean the restrictions , i.e. *-homomorphisms with commuting ranges and taking $\pi_A \times \pi_B$...So my first comment is not correct, because the right-hand side is the definition of the maximal norm.
Regarding your comment, I think you can pass to faithful *-homomorphisms without changing the norm or using minimality, here is the reason:

Comment: Suppose you have two non-faithful *-hom. $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$. Choose two faithful $*$-homomorphisms $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$. Now, the $*$-homomorphisms $(\pi_A\oplus \rho_A)$ and $(\pi_B\oplus \rho_B)$ are faithful, and they induce a norm greater than $\pi_A\otimes \pi_B$.
 So throwing in non-faithful representations into the collection of representations over which you are taking the supremum won't increase the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist, show that $(\oplus_{i\in I} H_i) \otimes (\oplus_{j\in J} K_j$) is canonically isomorphic to $\oplus_{i\in I, j\in J} H_i\otimes K_j$, 
as Hilbert spaces. You can see this exercise $3.2.2$ in Brown&Ozawa.

As you said, any $*$-homomorphism can be decomposed as a direct of degenerate part and cyclic $*$-homomorphisms. Once you know that, it suffices to show that for $\sigma_1: A\to B(H_1), \sigma_2: A\to B(H_2), \rho_1:B\to B(K_1)$ and $ \rho_2: B\to B(K_2)$ we get:
$||((\sigma_1\oplus \sigma_2)\otimes (\rho_1\oplus \rho_2))(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\otimes b_i)||=sup_{i,j\in\{1,2\}}||(\sigma_i\otimes \rho_j)(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\otimes b_i)||$.

As $(\sigma_1\oplus \sigma_2)\otimes (\rho_1\oplus \rho_2):A\odot B\to B(H_1\oplus H_2)\odot B(K_1\otimes K_2)\hookrightarrow B((H_1\oplus H_2)\otimes (K_1\oplus K_2))$
(I'm sure you know that there is an inclusion, because you need it as part of the proof that $||\ ||_{min}$ is indeed a norm. Anyway, you can find it in Brown&Ozawa Lemma $3.3.9.)$
So, by the isomorphism, and after identifications: 
$(\sigma_1\oplus \sigma_2)\otimes (\rho_1\oplus \rho_2): A\odot B\to B((H_1\otimes K_1)\oplus (H_1\otimes K_2)\oplus (H_2\otimes K_1)\oplus (H_2\otimes K_2))$.

Now, follow the isomorphism to verify that you get 
$((\sigma_1\oplus \sigma_2)\otimes (\rho_1\oplus \rho_2))(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\otimes b_i)= \oplus_{k,j\in \{1,2\}}\sigma_k\otimes \rho_j(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\otimes b_i)$,
 and it implies the desired result.

Of course, you can show it just for $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\rho_1$, because it is the same idea...

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot. It helps:)